# Misplaced \noalign following two newlines

Tags: tables, plain-tex, alignment, catcodes

Why does a `\noalign` command produce a `! Misplaced \noalign` when it follows at least two newlines.

For example, this code works :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
\halign{\strut #\cr First row\cr
\noalign{\hrule}Second row\cr}
\end{document}
```

But this one doesn't :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
\halign{\strut #\cr First row\cr

\noalign{\hrule}Second row\cr}
\end{document}
```

Is there any reason why ? I tried to play with catcodes and with the `^^M` character, but without success. Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example does `\cr\par\noalign`. The `\noalign` command must be immediatelly after `\cr`. The `\par` token is first token of the first column and you cannot use `\noalign` ans second token in the first column.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to suppress this behaviour?

Comment: Looking at the LaTeX source code, it seems that the following line `\let\par\@empty` solves the issue inside `tabular` environments.

Comment: Why do you need it? This is general TeX rule: empty line=\par. Suppressing this can break many other things. So, we must ask before such experiments: why do we need this exception? And in what scope?

Comment: This is in a custom tabular environment. I think it is safe to do so, as the tabular environment does the same thing.